# Moving Files and Folders to Google Shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm looking for a method to move (not copy) folders and files to a shared drive. I can do this manually through a drag and drop. Is there a way to do this programatically? The below code isn't successful. Any other options?

```
function moveToSharedDrive(){
  var source ='<Folder ID>'
  var destination='<Shared DriveID>'  

  var head = {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
  var options = {
    method: 'PATCH',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: head,
    muteHttpExceptions: false
  };
var fileMove = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${source}?supportsAllDrives=true&enforceSingleParent=true&addParents=${destination}`, options);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) or [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference)

Comment: This is using the Drive API

Comment: Those are your two choices. If you can't do it with them  then you can't do it.

Comment: Have you tried`Drive.Files.update(resource, fileId)`

Comment: @Cooper I have attemped without success.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your issue, can I ask you about the detail of `The below code isn't successful.`?

Comment: This is the error:  

Exception: Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "teamDrivesFolderMoveInNotSupported",
    "message": "Moving folders into sh.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From the error message, I think that the error message of `Moving folders into shared drives is not supported.` is shown. It seems that this is the current specification at Google. But, the files can be moved to the shared Drive. So as a workaround, how about the following flow? 1. Create a folder to the shared Drive. 2. Move the files to the created folder. I think that by this, your goal can be achieved. How about this? But I'm not sure about your folder structure from your question. So in the current stage, I cannot propose the sample script. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank youu for the comment. I have attempted to move to a folder in the shared drive and recieve the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `I have attempted to move to a folder in the shared drive and recieve the same error.`, I couldn't understand about what you moved. In the current stage, the folder cannot be moved to the shared Drive. But the file can be moved to the shared Drive. It seems that this is the current specification. I apologize for this.

Comment: I was missing the point about moving folders.